# Cannot print Drupal taxonomy terms in twig template

Tags: drupal, twig, taxonomy

Having trouble printing taxonomy terms in a Drupal twig template. Hoping someone can help.

I have a taxonomy vocabulary called "FAQ Category". Inside of it, there are several terms. I am trying to print all terms in a twig template called `views-view--faqs.html.twig`.

So far, I am able to print the term of the current page by using:

`{{ data.title|raw }}`

I can print the next and previous terms on the same page by using `data.previous.label` and `data.next.label`, and those are working fine.

What I need is to print all the terms, and I'm stuck. Ive tried several variations of for loops, such as:

```
{% for item in data %}
    {{ data.title|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

But that is not working. Any idea what I can do to print all of the terms?

Answer (score 1):

Your template file, looking by the name is pointing to a specific view.
I believe there is more than 1 ways to achieve it, but i suggest you to use a hook preprocess view.

check the docs here:https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x

Important:  you will need to paste that code inside mytheme.theme file (usually in themes/custom/mythemename, where mythemename is the name of your custom theme)

In the above link example, just add some new data, like this

```
$variables["mynewvar"] = 'my data';
```

then, you can print it into template

```
{{ mynewvar }}
```

Inside that hook, i would write an Entity Query in order to get all desired taxonomies.

Check this example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144147/get-taxonomy-terms

Then, i would append this values into the twig context, just like 'myvar' example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
{% for item in data.field_taxonomy %}
    {{ item.entity.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, no luck. I was hoping that since I can already call in terms using `data.next.label` and `data.previous.label`, that there would be an easy way to just call all of them.

I tried this to get all the variables of `data`:

```
{% for key, value in data  %}
    {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

and got values returned of: title, items, previous, next.

Does that help at all? This seems like such a simple thing to do in Wordpress, or even Drupal using Views, but twig is just fighting me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
https://www.drupal.org/project/kint

e.g

```
{{ kint(data) }}
```

This way you can explore the arrays and objects inside that variable.

Answer (score -1):

Good Assuming that you created a view with the taxonomies and defined the fields to show as title, body and the taxonomy that in this case I call it type_pf (frequently asked question type)

```
{% for row in content['#view'].result %}
  {{ content['#view'].field['title'].value(row) }}
  {{ content['#view'].field['body'].value(row) | raw}}
  {{ content['#view'].field['field_type_pf'].value(row) }}
{% endfor %}
```

That way the fields are displayed in the views. I don't know why it shows me the id in {{ content['#view'].field['field_tipo_pf'].value(row) }} instead the name of the taxonomy.

I hope this can help you! Cheers

Share
Edit
Delete
Flag

Comment: This is a copy of your other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72719849/2227743 Please don't.

Comment: If I understand what I did.
And it was not unintentionally, both questions needed the same answer.