# How to get a Taxonomy Term ID in Drupal/Twig view

Tags: drupal, twig, taxonomy

hope you doing well.


I'm starting with drupal.
and i was asked to change a

field class when it has a certain value previously defined as default.

if i insert this is the view `<p>{{ content.field_solution_by_default}}</p>`

it will print the Text of the field correctly, but to change the

class i need the "datavalue".

any one knows any way of doing this, i already tryed the followings:

```
{{ attribute(content.field_solution_by_default, datavalue) }}
{{ drupal_field(content, field_solution_by_default, tid) }}
{{ content.field_solution_by_default.0['#taxonomy_term']['tid'] }}
{{ content.field_solution_by_default['#taxonomy_term'][0].value }}
```

php 7.3
drupal 9.3

Comment: You mean to change the HTML class depending on the field value?

Answer (score 0):

Good. Assuming that you created a view with the taxonomies and defined the fields to show as title, body and the taxonomy: In this case, I call it `type_pf` (frequently asked question type):

```
{% for row in content['#view'].result %}
  {{ content['#view'].field['title'].value(row) }}
  {{ content['#view'].field['body'].value(row) | raw}}
  {{ content['#view'].field['field_type_pf'].value(row) }}
{% endfor %}
```

That way, the fields are displayed in the views.

That said, I don't know why it shows me the id instead the name of the taxonomy in:

```
{{ content['#view'].field['field_tipo_pf'].value(row) }}
```

Still, this should help.